# Ruby on Rails full_messages for specific attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails I can do this to get the full error message (includes the name of the attribute)

```
book.errors.full_messages.each do |err|
  puts err
end
```

My question is, how can I do the same thing but for a specific attribute?

I can't do this:

```
book.errors[:title].full_messages
```

As for now this is what I'm doing

```
book.errors[:title].each do |err|
  puts " Title #{err}"
end
```

I'm looking forward if there's a better way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the full error message for a specific attribute use [full_messages_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-full_messages_for):

```
book.errors.full_messages_for(:title)
```

Comment: This!, thanks. Didn't think `full_messages_for` does exist

Answer (score 2):

I think that strategy is appropriate. The errors method always returns an array, even if you specify a specific attribute, because there might be multiple errors associated with a single attribute. If only one attribute of `book` contains an error (lets say the `:title` attribute), there should be no difference between the outputs of these two methods:

```
book.errors.full_messages.each do |err|
  "#{err}"
end

book.errors[:title].each do |err|
  "#{err}"
end
```

Comment: @infused, apparently I don't have enough reputation to comment on your answer so I'll do so here: I wasn't aware of the `full_messages_for(:title)` method, is there a difference between it's output and the output of `errors[:title]`? Quickly testing it, they seem to output the same thing.

Comment: your first block will display all error messages including other attributes (ex : author, description etc) and what i want is only for title. Second block will only display error for title but won't include the name of the attribute ("can't be blank" instead of "Title can't be blank"). @infused's answer, `full_messages_for(:title)` differs from `errors[:title]` is it's adding the attribute name (ex : "Title can't be blank")

Comment: @AgungSetiawan Thanks!